# I want to loop through an object and pass the value to a new object while referencing another object

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I think this is a logic problem but say I have these 2 objects:

```
{
  players: {
    player1: {
      name: 'name1'
    },
    player2: {
      name: 'name2'
    },
    player3: {
      name: 'name3'
    },
    player4: {
      name: 'name4'
    },
    player5: {
      name: 'name5'
    }
  }
}

{
  users: {
    user1: {
      name: 'user1'
    },
    user2: {
      name: 'user2'
    }
  }
}
```

I want to loop through the players and assign a player to a user and move onto the next user and assign a player and so on. There will always be more users than players so it needs to go back to the start of the users object and carry on looping through the players object so I have an object at the end of it like so:

```
{
  assigned: {
    user1: {
      name: 'user1',
      players {
        player1: {...},
        player3: {...},
        player5: {...}
      }
    },
    user2: {
      name: 'user2',
      players {
        player2: {...},
        player4: {...}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can't think how to loop through ea player and user to create this object. Any advice is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is there any kind of logic that determines how many players will be assigned to one user? And do or don't you already have the code to pick a random non-assigned player?

Comment: There will be a finite number of players. We can say there will be a maximum of 10 players and the number of users will not exceed the number of players but can match it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your question correctly but I'll give it a try:

The below is an incomplete code, you'll have to complete it in javascript. Please keep in mind that you are creating a JSON object with circular dependencies meaning you can iterate in the json tree endlessly.

```
    var players = json.players;
    var users = json.users;

    // asigning users to players
    Object.keys(players).forEach(function(keyP) {
        var player = players[keyP];
        Object.keys(users).forEach(function(keyU) {
            var user = users[keyU];
            // custom logic to determine if user can be assigned
            // logic for assigning user
            if (!user.players) {
                user.players = {};
            }
            user.players[keyP] = player;
        });
    });

    // asigning players to users
    Object.keys(users).forEach(function(keyU) {
        var user = users[keyU];
        Object.keys(players).forEach(function(keyP) {
            var player = players[keyP];
            // custom logic to determine if player can be assigned
            // logic for assigning player
            if (!player.users) {
                player.users = {};
            }
            player.users[keyU] = user;
        });
    });
```